# How to make python output more decimal places of a recurring decimal?

Tags: python

````
```python
import decimal
x=[]
#functions etc. x is changed
#now returns is a list full of integers
print(sum(x)/len(x))
#This happens to give 0.6999
print(decimal.Decimal(sum(x)/len(x))
# This happens to give 0.6998999999996034 blah blah blah
```
````

The decimal module gives too many decimal places and round(decimal.Decimal(x),5) gives 0.69990

I would like it to output 0.69999(5 d.p.) but it outputs 0.6999 or 0.69990

Comment: would you please place your code here?

Comment: Hard to tell without your code, but a possibility may be taking the output with too many decimal places and [formatting it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) to fewer decimals.

Comment: you are using round function use float("{0:.5f}".format(x))

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, since the decimal you quoted - assuming it continues with 9s indefinitely - is mathematically equal to `0.6999`. It's not at all the same as the `0.69999` that you seem to want it to output.

Comment: The 9s don't go on forever

Comment: If you had done the math properly, converting to decimal *before* dividing instead of after, you would have gotten exactly 0.6999. Definitely not 0.69999. That's 0.00009 too high.

Comment: Ok, but even if they don't go on forever, your number is still very close to `0.6999`. It can't round to `0.69999` because that would need it to be between `0.699985` and `0.699995` - and your number is too small for that. This isn't a programming problem, it seems you simply misunderstand how rounding works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have the right answer: `round(decimal.Decimal(x),5)` which gives `0.69990`. In your case, you **should not** expect `0.69999`, it is not even close to `0.699899999999`. 
The python built-in function `round` is good to use, but sometimes it can be surprising, see more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#round)

To summary:

```
import decimal
x=0.699899999
print("x =", x)
g = round(decimal.Decimal(x),5)
print("rounded:", g)
```

output:

```
x = 0.699899999
rounded: 0.69990
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
x=0.6999932
g = float("{0:.5f}".format(x))
print(g)

#output be like
0.69999
```

Comment: In my case x=0.699899999..., this still seems to give me 0.6999, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I think this is a rounding issue, not decimal place issue. Try multiplying by 10000, convert to integer, then divide by 10000.

Answer (score 0):

The number `0.699899999999...` is mathematically equivalent to `0.6999000...`, assuming the `9`s repeat farther than we want to go before we round things off.

This is the same as the question of why `0.9999...` is equal to `1` (for which you can find many explanations online, I'm fond of [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TINfzxSnnIE) myself), just shifted several decimal places to the right. All the `9`s at the end turn into a `1`. That one gets added to the last `8` and turn it into a `9`. That's all followed by infinite zeros, which Python omits by default.

Comment: I'm sorry, the 9s don't go on forever.